# Filtering a list of lists of a tuple with regex

Tags: python, regex, tuples, list-comprehension

**SEE EDIT NEAR THE BOTTOM**

i'm just learning python.  I'm trying to filter a list of lists of a tuple to only keep the lists that contain tuples matching a regular expression.

Basically I have:

```
start_list=[[(blah1,123)],[(xblah2,123)],[(somethingelse1,123)],[(wookie1,123)]]
```

I want to regex filter for anything that contains "blah" in index 0 of the tuples.
Expected Results:

```
result_list=[[(blah1,123)],[(xblah2,123)]]
```

What I have so far:

```
import re
result_list=[[tup for tup in sub_list if re.search('.*blah.*',tup[0])] for sub_list in start_list]
```

However I keep getting errors with the regex

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

On top of that, I'm worried this will return blank lists for the tuples that don't match the regex.  Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

**EDIT**: OK my attempts at posing the problem more simply has led to me making typographic errors and such.  I apologize.  I'm using pysnmp getbulk and I wanted to get only the results that matched a base oid.  Here's what I get when I print the list of lists of a tuple:

```
[[(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.7.1.7.1.4.172.16.0.100.32.2.0.16777724.1.4.172.16.0.89), Integer(16777724))], [(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.7.1.7.1.4.172.16.0.100.32.2.0.16777724.1.4.172.16.0.90), Integer(16777724))], [(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.7.1.7.1.4.172.16.0.160.27.2.0.16778357.0.0), Integer(16778357))], [(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.7.1.7.1.4.172.16.0.192.29.2.0.16778348.0.0), Integer(16778348))]]
```

I'm just realized this ObjectName thing isn't a string so I guess I can't use regex on it.  But I do want to filter for the tuples that have the ObjectName that matches a base oid of:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.7.1.7.1.4.172.16.0.100.32
```

I need to google what this ObjectName thing is now...

Comment: `start_list` doesn't look like a list of lists of tuples to me. The last two elements don't contain any tuples at all.

Comment: @Kevin that is his question exactly. His list contains elements that are NOT lists of tuples, and he wants to do away with that.

Comment: I think we are reading the question differently, then. I hear "This list contains only lists of tuples, and I want to keep the ones that match this regex", and you hear "this list contains, in addition to other things, lists of tuples, and I want to keep the ones that are lists of tuples and that match this regex"

Comment: In any case, when I run this code I get `NameError: name 'blah1' is not defined`. OP, please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Why did you post a partial traceback for code calling `re.match()` but show us code using `re.search()` here?

Comment: @Kevin I think you may be right. Defining it as `(blah1,123)` instead of `('blah1',123)` and then failing to put tuples AT ALL in the elements he wanted to skip may have led me astray.

Comment: Oh sorry guys, I typoed, the last two were tuples as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because I tried both match and search and pasted the wrong out.

Comment: Ok I think I need to add more details to this as there are a few things that are probably unclear.  Let me edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @warunsl for the lambda piece to remove empty lists from my list. I ended up figuring it out after commenters pointed out the tuples didn't contain strings. I used str() to convert the objects in the tuples to strings and ran the regex on that. What I ended up with was:

```
result_list = filter(lambda x: x, [[tup for tup in sub_list if re.match('1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.7.1.7.1.4.172.16.0.100.32', str(tup[0]))] for sub_list in start_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with the fact that the last two lists don't contain tuples, you have to do your for loop the other way.

```
[tup for sublist in start_list for tup in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp can be used only on string. You should write your tuple as ("xblah2",123).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a list of (string,int) tuples:

```
start_list = [("blah1",123),("xblah2",123),("somethingelse1",123),("wookie1",123)]
```

You can use `in` to do the check instead of regex.

```
result_list = [t for t in start_list if "blah" in t[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, in your `result_list` which is as nested list comprehension, the outer list comprehension returns `sub_list`. So the inner list comprehension should be working on that.

Also, the precise reason why you are getting a expected string or buffer error is because none of your `blah1`, `xblah2`, `somethinglese1`, etc are strings. Assuming they are strings and fixing the list comprehension we have:

```
result_list = [[tup for tup in sub_list if re.search('.*blah.*',sub_list[0][0])] for sub_list in start_list]
```

This will result in empty lists as you mentioned.

```
[[('blah1', 123)], [('xblah2', 123)], [], []]
```

To fix that, you filter the above list comprehension for empty lists

```
result_list = filter(lambda x: x, [[tup for tup in sub_list if re.search('.*blah.*',sub_list[0][0])] for sub_list in start_list])
```

Note, `lambda x: x` is same as `lambda x: len(x)>0`

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, they are not strings so I still have to figure that out. I will use your lambda trick for filtering the empty lists.